# How to parse syslog message using logstash

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration, elk

Hi I have a syslog made up of two events

```
Jul  6 13:24:27 NODE1 zeus.eventd[14176]: pools/POOL nodes/IP:3000 nodefail Node NODE2 has failed - A monitor has detected a failure

Jul  6 13:24:34 NODE1 zeus.eventd[14176]: pools/POOL nodes/IP:3000 nodeworking Node NODE2 is working again
```

I would like to pull NODE2 from the syslog and add it as a field in the index along with nodefail/nodeworking

Currently my input/grok is

```
   syslog {
       grok_pattern => "%{SYSLOGLINE}"
   }
```

with no filter however all of the info I need is populated in a "message" field so I am unable to use it in elastic

I know the position what I want in the syslog line I just need to pull it out and add it as a field

Is anyone able show me the input/filter config I need in order to achieve this?

Thanks,

TheCube

Edit: The message fields look like this:

```
zeus.eventd 14176 - - SERIOUS   pools/POOL  nodes/IP:3000   nodefail    Node NODENAME has failed - A monitor has detected a failure
zeus.eventd 14176 - - INFO  pools/POOL  nodes/IP:3000   nodeworking Node NODENAME is working again
```

Comment: the grok pattern to parse the `message` field should look like this `^pools/POOL nodes/IP:\d+ %{WORD:status} Node %{WORD:node_name}`; you could also use the dissect filter, which is easier to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [dissect filter plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-dissect.html) on the message field created while parsing with `%{SYSLOGLINE}`:

```
dissect {
  mapping => {
    "message" => "%{} %{} %{status} %{} %{node_name} %{}"
  }
}
```

---

Or a second grok filter, applied on the message field created while parsing with `%{SYSLOGLINE}`, with this pattern:

```
^pools/POOL nodes/IP:\d+ %{WORD:status} Node %{WORD:node_name}
```

In both cases, with the logs given in your question, you get those results:

```
"status":"nodefail"
"node_name":"NODE2"

"status":"nodeworking"
"node_name":"OFSVDBM101"
```

Comment: Ok so I can use dissect to split up the message field created by %{SYSLOGLINE}?
I have updated the description with the contents of the message field
You can see that it's only the last part that is different

Comment: @TheCube yes. When you parse a message with %{SYSLOGLINE}, it creates new fields (and overwrite the `message` field. Those fields then can be used like the others. I'll update the answer so that it's clearer

Comment: thanks I have updated the description with the contents of the message field if that helps

Comment: thanks for your help. this was fiddly but it did work!